# Android Integrating Facebook - Getting FQL response in changed order

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I am developing an android application which includes the facebook integration. If I execute multiple fql queries, I am getting the response in changed order.

I am using the following code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> photoAlbumIdArr = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     photoAlbumIdArr = new ArrayList<String>();
     photoAlbumIdArr.add("111114545_25133454545");
     photoAlbumIdArr.add("111114590_25133434768");
     photoAlbumIdArr.add("111114232_2513345487");
     photoAlbumIdArr.add("111114512_25133454456");
     startProgress();
}
public void startProgress() {
    // Do something long
    PhotoGalleryActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String fqlQuery = "";

            for(int k=0;k<photoAlbumIdArr.size();k++)
            {
                fqlQuery = "SELECT pid, src FROM photo WHERE aid = '"+photoAlbumIdArr.get(k)+"'";
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

                session = Session.getActiveSession();
                Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params,
                        HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                String jsonResponse = response.toString();
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, jsonResponse);
                            }
                        });
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here the callback response is called after the for loop completed. In that I am getting the unorder response(i.e) getting first album photos as last or middle response likewise. What may be the problem. Why I get the unordered response.

Comment: Can I know why I got down voted? Then only I can improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that you do not have an ORDER BY clause in your FQL query.

Try using something like:

`SELECT pid, src FROM photo WHERE aid = '{album id}' ORDER BY modified`

This will ensure that the order that is returned is always the same (assuming no images are modified in-between queries).